# Illegal start of expression, not sure why

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm a first year programmer and not completely certain on what I'm doing wrong with this code. Please, can anyone help?

```
package ________;

public class _______  
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        public int getFactorial(int number)
        {
            if (number == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Returned 1");
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                int factor = number * getFactorial(number - 1);
                System.out.println("Returned " + factor);
                return factor;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

This line displays an illegal start of expression method every time I attempt to compile or run the program:

```
public int getFactorial(int number)
```

The **____**'s just represent the hidden package and class names. Using NetBeans IDE 7.4, Java apllication

Comment: You can't have a method inside a method in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have other methods or functions inside the `main` function. You can however call the functions from your main function.

Please write the code as

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int number = 10;
    /* if you want user to input */
    Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
    number = get.nextInt(); // get the next integer user types :)
    getFactorial(number);
} 

public static int getFactorial(int number)
{
    int factor = 1;
    if (number == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Returned 1");
    }
    else
    {
        factor = number * getFactorial(number - 1);
        System.out.println("Returned " + factor);
    }
    return factor;
}
```

This way, your function would be inside the same Class but outside the bounds of Main method. In the main method, you would be calling it and where the control would be transfering to the getFactorial function.

Comment: +1, @ZouZou, thanks alot sir. I almost forgot those essential parts. :)

Comment: @ZouZou but this time, `factor` was initialized outside, `if` block.

Comment: Could I ask, how would I now make number a user input number?

Comment: @Sculler, sure brother why not! :) and yeaah, you can use constants values as well as user-provided values in your code! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a method (`getFactorial`) inside another (`main`). They need to come one after another.

Comment: so what should go inside the main then?

Comment: @Sculler *calls* to other methods. you should read about Java basics.

Comment: main is the entry point to your program. You can call methods in there, but not define them

Comment: so I would call the public int inside the main, but would define it outside?

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
      getFactorial(int number);

    }
  public static int getFactorial(int number)
  {
    if (number == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Returned 1");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int factor = number * getFactorial(number - 1);
        System.out.println("Returned " + factor);
        return factor;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Remember that non-static method cant be referenced form static context.

Comment: Sure. As mentioned above you can not declare a method within a method.  getThis(){ GetThat{}}} would be illegal.  Separate out your methods. This not only for compiling reasons, but it is good OOP design. Yes, thanks for catching that Pshemo!  It is late!

Comment: Thank you so much :D I din't completely catch the multiple method possibilities or recursion until now, but this explained so much. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, recursion is a great idea.  There are always multiple ways of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write a method inside another method. Your code should look like this:

```
package ________;

public class _______ {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //call getFactorial, for example
        int result = getFactorial(2);
    }

    public static int getFactorial(int number) {
        if (number == 1) {
            System.out.println("Returned 1");
            return 1;
        } else {
            int factor = number * getFactorial(number - 1);
            System.out.println("Returned " + factor);
            return factor;
        }

    }

}
```